# Trying to search & replace within brackets using sed

Tags: sed

I have a json file which among other settings, contains the following data:

```
"school": {
    "name": "qwerty",
    "key": "user",
    "secret": "pass",
    "class": ["str1/str2:str3"],
    "grades": []
},
```

I'm trying to replace `str1/str2:str3` with `abc/def:123`
For this I tried using:

```
sed -i -e 's/"class": \[".+"\]/"class": \["abc/def:123"\]/g' config.json
```

But it doesn't work, no error message. Any advise?
ps. the format str1/str2:str3 occurs in other places in the config file, therefore I included the "class" in the regex pattern.

Comment: Please post valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird, I'm getting an error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 37: unknown option to `s'
```

It shows one of the problems: the `/` must be backslashed, or you need to use a different delimiter.

The second problem is the `+`. It needs to be backslashed, too, but in some sed versions, if I remember correctly, you need to use `-E` to make it available at all, and then it shouldn't be backslashed.

E.g. this works for me in GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's="class": \[".+"\]="class": \["abc/def:123"\]=g'
```

Comment: I ended up testing with -E and escaping the / with a backslash \/ and then it worked. Thanks for the help, due to my new account I can't vote yet but I selected your answer as solving the issue